# React native firebase permission denied

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to read/write to a firebase database. I have in firebase made authentication open to all.

[image]

In my code

[image]

Where I console log firebase I see in 
[image]

so it looks like I am connecting to firebase. However in my code in where I try to add to the database:

```
    firebase.database().ref().set(
  {
    month: 'January',
    quote: 'test'
  }
).then(() => {
  console.log('INSERTED !');
});
```

I get an error of permission denied in my console.

------------------------------Got it working
Have to select realtime database and fix permissions there. I was fixing permissions in the wrong place!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be occurring because while you've set access rules for Firestore, you're actually trying to write to the old Firebase realtime database. Go to the dashboard for the realtime database and modify the access rules there, assuming that you'd like to use the realtime database.